# Array Several Columns to One with Column Headers as Separate Column

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to take several columns in Google Sheets and combine them into one with the column header in an adjacent cell.

I would like to go from something like this:

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

I am currently achieving this by arraying the first column over and over for the number of columns. I am then arraying each column on on top of another so something like this:

```
 Column 1              Column 2
={A1:A4;A1:A4;A1:A4}  ={B1:B4;C1:C4;D1:D4}
```

In a third column I am using an if-then statements to get the Column name wherever the name column = "Name"

My issue is when I am trying to do this with several columns is becomes very tedious to build out these arrays. I am looking for help with a single formula to achieve this by just referencing the range for all columns.

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?  Based on your example, a pivot table should be able to do what you need.

Comment: @RonKloberdanz How might I configure? Ive played with the pivot option for a while and am unable to get the result above. Additionally, am I able to pivot from data on several pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tricky, but possible. For explanatory reason I am not putting everything into one, convoluted formula, but present step by step solution. DISCLAIMER: It's fast one, so it in not perfect.

## Assumptions:

1. "Start" data are in Sheet named "Data"
2. Result is in Sheet named "Result"

## Procedure

Add one column (A) to "start" data with this code in A1 (it will be our index):

```
=ArrayFormula(if(B1:B<>"";row(A1:A)-1;""))
```

[image]

In "Result" sheet put in A1 this code:

```
=ArrayFormula(INT((ROW(B1:INDIRECT("C"&(COUNTA(Data!$B1:B)-1)*4))-1)/4)+1)
```

[image]

In B1 this code:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A1:A<>"";VLOOKUP(A1:A;Data!A1:E;2;0);"" ))
```

[image]

In C1 this:

```
=transpose(SPLIT(REPT(TEXTJOIN("*";1;Data!C1:1)&"*";COUNTUNIQUE(B1:B));"*";0;0))
```

[image]

In D1 this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR( VLOOKUP(B1:B;Data!B1:F;MATCH(C1:C;Data!B1:F1;0));""))
```

[image]

Finally in F1 - to clean the result put this:

```
={{"Name"\"Column"\"Number"};{B1:D20}}
```

[image]

## Link to working copy

[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Cr2mleteSngkmYMRHV49a3Fid83HpxzM5JNXFvMwUc/edit?usp=sharing)

## Final thoughts

1. You can pack everything into one formula
2. Its very hasty solution, so it will not expand to more than 4 columns by itself (One, Two, etc). This is hard-coded now. If you can't figure it out, just give me a comment - I will show this places / fix them to make it dynamic

Comment: This works perfectly for my use case. Super helpful!

Comment: Glad I could help :)